# Planet should have been colonized years ago

Tags: technical-issues, stellaris

I was playing Stellaris as I had just gotten the Federations DLC and wanted to try it out.

I had a planet that was taking a really long time to colonize, and when I check on it, it said this:

[image: A planet saying it will be colonized by 2233.01.01 despite it being 2236.03.28]

I think this happened because I integrated a vassal while this planet was in the process of colonization but I am not really sure.

Is there a way to finish its colonization or stop it so I can start it again?

Mod List:

- [No Edge Scrolling](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=682005202)
- [Tiny Outliner](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1610578060)
- [Tiny Fleets](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1629519297)
- [Start with AutoExplore](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1394094004)
- [More AI Personalitys](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=701432146)
- [Uncle Gabby's Simple Gender Editor](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2030200989)
- [Cinematic Loading Screens](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2467105449)

Comment: I had a fleet that wasn't firing while being fired upon, so it was slowly being defeated by an inferior fleet. It was solved by saving, exiting and restarting the executable, followed by loading that save. That procedure caused the fleet to respond to the hostilities. I don't know whether it would work in your case, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Since you are using mods, include your modlist. All of them, not just the ones you think are relevant.

Comment: @Studoku Is that good?